# php cron job not running, Amzonz EC2, bitnami

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, cron, bitnami

I have tried all of the following variations in my cron.d/cron file:

```
0 * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/crons/my_script.php
*/5 * * * * su - bitnami -s /bin/sh -c "/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php -c /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/crons/my_script.php cron:run"
*/5 * * * * su - bitnami -c "/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/crons/my_script.php"
*/5 * * * * php /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/crons/my_script.php
```

None of the above seem to work.  Here are my permissions:

```
 sudo ls -l cron
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Nov 24 16:13 cron

sudo ls -l /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/crons/my_script.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38884 Nov 17 20:39 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/crons/my_script.php
```

Comment: You forgot the string which state who should run the script `0 * * * * root /my/command/..`

Comment: That throws an error

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. The WordPress' folder permissions are configured for the bitnami user and daemon group to have permissions to write and read in it (more information [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKfle7O0vN8&list=PLGgVZHi3XQNn4x0DU7Qj1r_inej3xEUda)). Did you try to run the script using the bitnami user or the daemon one? If that works, you just simply need to configure the cronjob to use any of those users.

Comment: @JobbieDaddy What error? Could you be more specific? Everything under `cron.d` require to specify which user to execute